# Ruby gem common deployement for all apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

I am trying to deploy APM solution provided by scout app. Scout apm documentation says I need to install a gem in all the applications I am running on the server. I have multiple applications running on single server. All my ruby applications are located at `/var/www`. Is there a way I can deploy that apm gem in one place and then it can be used for all the services. so that I don't need to add it in each application `Gemfile` and its config file in `config` folder. I know I can achieve it using a shell script however problem with that approach is all the apps have their own git repo which would be administrative overhead for me.

Comment: Why is adding the dependency to each `Gemfile` problematic? Sounds like a very easy solution to me.

Comment: I have 90+ such applications where in I have to do this exercise. Isn't that administrative overhead?

Comment: Do your applications already have a "shared logic" gem? You could potentially add this as a runtime dependency of that gem. Otherwise ... You could just write a little shell script to update all 90+ Gemfiles in one go.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to add gems that you want to use in an application to the `Gemfile`. Because if you do not add that gem to an application's `Gemfile` then the application will simply not load that gem.

Another option might be to install the gem globally ion the server and `require` that gem in each application manually. But that still means you have to add a `require 'gem_name'` to all applications and this is error-prone because you lose the magic provided by `bundler`.

tl;dr: No, you have to add the gem to each application's `Gemfile`.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Or only this way by adding gem to all apps. Like Common Gemfile where in we can put common gems used by all apps.